# Counterexample of certain non-primary ideals

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with unit. Let $I,J$ be primary ideals of $A$ such that $J$ is not contained in $I$ and $r(J)\subset r(I)$, $r(J)\neq r(I)$. Then $I\cap J$ is not necessarily primary.

I did not find counter  examples in $\mathbb{Z}$. I am confused about polynomial rings. How to give an example?

Comment: The reason you didn't find any examples in $\Bbb Z$ is that the primary ideals are zero or of the form $(p^k)$ for prime $p$ and positive integer $k$. The radical of $(p^k)$ is always $(p)$. You can see that since the nonzero prime ideals are maximal, it's not possible to get $r(J)\subsetneq r(I)$ unless $J=0$, but then $J\subseteq I$. This holds for all principal ideal domains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could take $R = k[x,y]$ where $k$ is a field, $J = (x)$, and $I = (x^2,y)$. The ideal $J$ is primary since it is prime and $I$ is primary since $\sqrt{I} = (x,y)$ is maximal. Then one has $J \not\subseteq I$ and $J \subsetneq \sqrt{I}$. Finally, $J \cap I = (x^2,xy)$ shows that $x^2$ is part of a minimal generating set of $J \cap I$; hence it is not primary. Or one can use that $J \cap I$ is a primary decomposition of itself.